# nvcc/CUDA 6.5 & c++11(future) - gcc 4.4.7

Tags: c++11, gcc, cuda, future

When I compile the following code containing the design C++11, I get errors - it does not compile. I've tried with different flags, but I haven't found a solution.

My setting: CUDA 6.5, gcc 4.4.7
I am not able to change the settings. 
How can I still make this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "KD_tree.h"
#include "KD_tree.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <future>
#define MYDEVICE 0

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //do something..... 

    cudaDeviceProp devProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&devProp, MYDEVICE);
    printDevProp(devProp);
    int max_threads = devProp.warpSize;

   //do something else ... 

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried compiling with different flags:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 cudaMain.cu KD_tree.cpp -arch=sm_20 -o tree.out
In file included from cudaMain.cu:14:
simple_kd_tree.h:12:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
cudaMain.cu:19:18: error: future: No such file or directory


nvcc --std=c++11 cudaMain.cu KD_tree.cpp -arch=sm_20 -o tree.out
In file included from cudaMain.cu:14:
simple_kd_tree.h:12:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
cudaMain.cu:19:18: error: future: No such file or directory


nvcc --std=c++11 cudaMain.cu KD_tree.cpp -arch=sm_20 -c -o tree.out
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
```

Do I have to split the c++ part? How would I do this exactly?

Comment: `#include "KD_tree.cpp"` in cudaMain.cu **and** adding KD_tree.cpp to the compile command line is almost certainly not what you want to do.  If you can compile KD_tree.cpp successfully with your existing g++, then you may have good results by removing the c++11 features (i.e. `<future>`) from cudaMain.cu, and compile (`-c`) cudaMain.cu with nvcc, and compile (`-c`) KD_tree.cpp with g++, and then link the two objects together.  There are many example questions demonstrating this here on the cuda tag.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I will do it like this as soon, as I've got more kernels going on. I believe with the above code it might be possible to change `cudaMain.cu` into `cudaMain.cpp` and compile the whole thing with gcc 4.8 ? I've been trying this for some time now but get `undefined reference to `cudaGetDeviceProperties'`as an error. Do you know what I have to put as a flag? I've `#include "cuda.h" #include "cuda_runtime.h"`.

Comment: I've found the solution: `g++ -std=gnu++11 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -I/usr/local/cuda/include main.cpp KD_tree.hpp -lstdc++ -pthread -o test.out -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcudart -lcuda` for anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11 support is added officially in CUDA 7.0. And you need GCC version 4.7 or later to have C++11 support.
See details here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-compiler-new-features